# How to interact with database after Cucumber scenario finishes via hooks.rb?

Tags: ruby, database, cucumber, hook, sequel

So, I'm doing some data logging and need to insert a row into a table via an "After do" hook.

My current hook is:

```
After do
   puts 'before'
   FactoryGirl.create :'db/table', {:column => 'value'}
   puts 'after'
end
```

Somehow, both 'before' and 'after' print out, yet the row does not get inserted.

I think the DB connection closes immediately after the scenario ends, which prevents the insert.

Is there any way to get this row inserted?

Comment: If the connection were closed when FactoryGirl ran I'd expect an error. How are you cleaning up after each scenario and how are you checking the existence of the row?